# Unable to access List<t> count property from web control

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a custom web control that I need to obtain the count of the number of objects from a List object inside the control.  In more detailed terms, I have a List property that I need maintain and know the number of Audiences that exist in the list on the web page.  Unfortunately, the Count always returns 0, even though I'm adding items to the List.

At various places during the code execution the count is correct, but once I return to the .aspx page, it's like the object has been completely erased again.  I'm thinking that my Web Control keeps overwriting the values every time the page loads, but I'm not sure how to prevent that if that is the case.

This is my first project using some of these techniques so I may be approaching things wrong to begin with.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Base object:

```
public class Audience
{
    public String name { get; set; }
    public String id { get; set; }
    public Int16 type { get; set; }

    public Audience() { }
 }
```

Enumerable class List<Audience>:

```
public class Audiences : IEnumerable
{

    List<Audience> audienceList = new List<Audience>();

    public Audiences() { }

    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        return (IEnumerator)this;
    }

    public void addToList(List<Audience> audiences)
    {
        foreach (Audience audience in audiences)
        {
            audienceList.Add(audience);
        }
    }

    public int count()
    {
        return audienceList.Count();
    }
}
```

AudienceControl Web Control Class:

```
public partial class AudienceControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    public Audiences audienceList = new Audiences();


    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if ((Audiences)ViewState["audienceList"]!=null)
            audienceList = (Audiences)ViewState["audienceList"];
    }

    //Other functions to add/search/etc...

   protected void add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       List<Audience> audiences = new List<Audience>();
       ...
       audienceList.addToList(audiences);

       ViewState["audienceList"] = audienceList;
    }
 }
```

.ASPX code that always returns zero.

```
    Page_Load() 
   {
       Response.Write("The audience count is " + AudienceControl.audienceList.count());
   }
```

**Code that does work:**

```
    protected void Page_LoadComplete(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (AudienceControl.audienceList != null)
        {
            Response.Write("The audience count is " + AudienceControl.audienceList.count());
        }
    }
```

**Edit:**
Added add_Click() code to Web Control to show where audienceList.addToList() is being called.

**Solution Found:**
The problem apparently resides in the page lifecyle.  The custom controls are not loaded when the Page_Load event fires, so there's no audienceList object **yet** to provide any data even if stored to ViewState.  However, when I added Page_LoadComplete and tested the count there, the count is correct.  Thank you to all of you who asked questions and provided feedback.  I appreciate your time and willingness to help.

Comment: Where are you adding items? Are you sure you are adding them to the same instance of `Audiences` as the one you are calling `Count` on?

Comment: Any reason you use `AudienceControl.audienceList.count()` when I believe you want `AudienceControl.Count()`?

Comment: whoisj, just trying to figure out the problem.  Both methods refer to the same property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All member variables are erased between page loads, unless you take steps to preserve them (e.g. store them in ViewState, or save/retrieve them from session/database).

Comment: John, I added the ViewState as you suggested as you bring up a very good point.  However, I still have the same result.

Comment: You need to remove this line from the click handler: `List<Audience> audiences = new List<Audience>();`.  Currently your code just stomps on the instance that was just restored from ViewState.

Comment: John, thank you, but unless I'm missing something there shouldn't be a conflict as the instance names are different.  I take the audiences instance and add them to the audienceList object via addToList().  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason you are inheriting from IEnumerable? There doesn't seem to be a reason for it with the code that you have posted, however there obviously might be more to the class than what you have here. Anyways, I believe the problem might be in your `GetEnumerator` method. Try:

```
return audienceList.GetEnumerator;
```

Comment: Ncholas, I used IENumberable because I wanted to do a foreach loop and thought that was required.

Comment: You do need IEnumerable for a foreach loop, however with your implementation you are simply using a list's built in methods anyways and returning those. I would recommend using a simple getter/setter for your audienceList in Audiences. So then to loop through all of the Audience objects it would be something along the lines of `foreach(var currentAudience in Audiences.audienceList)`

Comment: Cool, thanks.  I'll give that a try.   +++ for the example.